# Saving records of javascript application

Tags: javascript

**I want to prepare an educative game like ;**

```js
// constant variables 
var constants = new (function() {
    var rows = 3;
    var columns = 6;
    var numMatches = (rows * columns) / 2;
    this.getRows = function() { return rows; };
    this.getColumns = function() { return columns; };
    this.getNumMatches = function() { return numMatches; };
})();

// Global Variables
var currentSessionOpen = false;
var previousCard = null;
var numPairs = 0;

// this function creates deck of cards that returns an object of cards 
// to the caller
function createDeck() {
 var rows = constants.getRows();
 var cols = constants.getColumns();
 var key = createRandom();
 var deck = {};
 deck.rows = [];

 // create each row
 for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = {};
  row.cards = [];
  
  // creat each card in the row
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   var card = {};
   card.isFaceUp = false;
   card.item = key.pop();
   row.cards.push(card);
  }
  deck.rows.push(row);
 }
 return deck;
}

// used to remove something form an array by index
function removeByIndex(arr, index) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}

function insertByIndex(arr, index, item) {
 arr.splice(index, 0, item);
}

// creates a random array of items that contain matches
// for example: [1, 5, 6, 5, 1, 6]
function createRandom() {
 var matches = constants.getNumMatches();
 var pool = [];
 var answers = [];
 var letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'
     , 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'
     , 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
 
 var hiragana = ['あ', 'い', 'う', 'え', 'お', 'か', 'が', 'き'
     , 'ぎ', 'く', 'ぐ', 'け', 'げ', 'こ', 'ご', 'さ'
     , 'ざ', 'し', 'じ', 'す', 'ず', 'せ', 'ぜ', 'そ'
     , 'ぞ', 'た', 'だ', 'ち', 'ぢ', 'つ', 'づ', 'て'
     , 'で', 'と', 'ど', 'な', 'に', 'ぬ', 'ね', 'の'
     , 'は', 'ば', 'ぱ', 'ひ', 'び', 'ぴ', 'ふ', 'ぶ'
     , 'ぷ', 'へ', 'べ', 'ぺ', 'ほ', 'ぼ', 'ぽ', 'ま'
     , 'み', 'む', 'め', 'も', 'や', 'ゆ', 'よ', 'ら'
     , 'り', 'る', 'れ', 'ろ', 'わ', 'を', 'ん'];
 // set what kind of item to display
 var items = hiragana;

 // create the arrays for random numbers and item holder
 for (var i = 0; i < matches * 2; i++) {
  pool.push(i); // random numbers
 }
 
 // generate an array with the random items
 for (var n = 0; n < matches; n++) {
  // grab random letter from array and remove that letter from the
  // original array
  var randLetter = Math.floor((Math.random() * items.length));
  var letter = items[randLetter];
  removeByIndex(items, randLetter);
  // generate two random placements for each item
  var randPool = Math.floor((Math.random() * pool.length));
  
  // remove the placeholder from answers and insert the letter into 
  // random slot
  insertByIndex(answers, pool[randPool], letter);
  
  // remove random number from pool
  removeByIndex(pool, randPool);
  
  // redo this process for the second placement
  randPool = Math.floor((Math.random() * pool.length));
  insertByIndex(answers, pool[randPool], letter);

  // remove rand number from pool
  removeByIndex(pool, randPool);
 }
 return answers;
} 

var app = angular.module('cards', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller("CardController", function($scope, $timeout) {
 $scope.deck = createDeck();
 $scope.isGuarding = true;
 $scope.inGame = false;

 $scope.check = function(card) {
  if (currentSessionOpen && previousCard != card && previousCard.item == card.item && !card.isFaceUp) {
   card.isFaceUp = true;
   previousCard = null;
   currentSessionOpen = false;
   numPairs++;
  } else if(currentSessionOpen && previousCard != card && previousCard.item != card.item && !card.isFaceUp) {
   $scope.isGuarding = true;
   card.isFaceUp = true;
   currentSessionOpen = false;   
   $timeout(function() {
    previousCard.isFaceUp = card.isFaceUp = false;
    previousCard = null;
    $scope.isGuarding = $scope.timeLimit ? false : true;
   }, 1000);
  } else {
   card.isFaceUp = true;
   currentSessionOpen = true;
   previousCard = card;
  } 

  if (numPairs == constants.getNumMatches()) {
   $scope.stopTimer();
  }
 } //end of check()

 // for the timer
 $scope.timeLimit = 60000;
 $scope.isCritical = false;
 
 var timer = null;

 // start the timer as soon as the player presses start
 $scope.start = function(){
  // I need to fix this redundancy. I initially did not create this
  // game with a start button.
  $scope.deck = createDeck();
  // set the time of 1 minutes and remove the cards guard
  $scope.timeLimit = 60000;
  $scope.isGuarding = false;
  $scope.inGame = true;

  ($scope.startTimer =function() {
   $scope.timeLimit -= 1000;
   $scope.isCritical = $scope.timeLimit <= 10000 ? true : false;
   
   timer = $timeout($scope.startTimer, 1000);
   if ($scope.timeLimit === 0) {
    $scope.stopTimer();
    $scope.isGuarding = true;
   }
  })();
 } 
 // function to stop the timer
 $scope.stopTimer = function() {
   $timeout.cancel(timer);
   $scope.inGame = false;
   previousCard = null;
   currentSessionOpen = false;
   numPairs = 0;
 }

});
```

```css
.card_container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1px auto;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 9em;
  height: 12em;
  line-height: 12em;
  z-index: 1;
}
.card_container {
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  perspective: 1000;
}
.card {
  background-color: #68c39f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0.5px 2.5px #ccc;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s linear;
  transition: all .25s linear;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
.flip .card{
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  backface-visibility: hidden; 
}
.face.back {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-size: 7.5em;
  background-color: #FFCC66;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.timer {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #1abc9c;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
}

.startbtn {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.critical {
  color: red;
}

.cntr {
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.points {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="cards">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flip.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-animate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
<body>
 <div class="cntr" ng-controller="CardController">
  <div class="timer" ng-class="{critical:isCritical}">
   {{timeLimit | date: 'm:ss'}}  
  </div>
  <table class="table-top">
   <tr ng-repeat="row in deck.rows">
    <td ng-repeat="card in row.cards">
     <div class="card_container {{!card.isFaceUp ? '' : 'flip'}}" ng-click="isGuarding || check(card)" >
      <div class="card shadow">
       <div class="front face"></div>
       <div class="back face text-center pagination-center">
        <p> {{card.item}} </p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div class="startbtn">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" ng-disabled="inGame == true" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
  </div>

 </div>
</html>
```

I can edit the snippet in the link however there is something more that i want to add this example. I want to keep the records of players as list below the application.

What is the best way of doing this.

Need your helps. Thanks from now on.

Comment: I think you're going to need to give more detail about what you're asking here to get a good answer.

Comment: what details do i need to specify? Before players start to play  they will write their player id and then it will keep their records in mysql or another database system

Comment: Like what does "as list below the application" mean? How permanent of records do you want to keep? Do you want to keep them client side or server side? "Best way" according to what metric?

Comment: A description of what the code even does would probably help too.

Comment: i have a wordpress site it works with php-mysql connection so i want to create a table in my database and keep players id and record in this table with the help of php ? if it is possible :(

Comment: Of course that's possible. Have you ever used a SQL database?

Comment: yes i did actually im good with mysql side but i do not know how to get records data with user id and send this data to database

Comment: You need to learn AJAX. AJAX is the most common, basic way to send data back and forth between a server and client. Very easy to use once you understand asynchronous programming. You can use JQuery to make it easier, but no libraries are necessary to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your app has access to internet then try https://firebase.google.com/, they provide very good JS SDK for Realtime Database and Storage with free plan. 
   Here you can find information how to start with it in your project: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup
2. If your app does not have access then you can use localStorage, WebSQL or IndexedDB which supplies with modern browsers.

If you need some help with integration firebase to your project let me know.

Comment: i feel as if a doctor spoken to me in Latin. understood nothing dear master. :( i think i should give up

Comment: No no, don't give up (here you start your account  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start  and here you learn how to write or fetch data https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write). Look you are using AngularJS so you can easely use https://github.com/firebase/angularfire.